# Find a node in a generic tree using recursion in python

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, search, tree

I want to find a node in a generic tree using recursion, but i can't seem to to get it working.I made it as a method in a class, and am only posting the method.I'm using python 3.Any help would be appreciated

```
def search_tree2(self, node):
    if self.name == node.name:
        return self
    elif self.child_nodes:
        result = None
        for child in self.child_nodes:
            if child.name == node.name:
                result = child
            elif child.child_nodes:
                result = child.search_tree2(child)
                if result.child_nodes:
                    for kid in result.child_nodes:
                        if kid.name == node.name:
                            result = kid
        return result
    else:
        return None
```

Edit:Added the rest of the code, with a updated method from Neel Mehta.For clarity what I am trying to do is to add a node to the tree at any node in the tree by searching for the node,and then adding the new node.Also I am on mobile so it is a bit hard to paste the code; thats why I initially only posted the code snippet.

```
class Tree:
    def __init__(self, value=None, name=None, parent=None):
        self.value = value
        self.name = name
        self.parent = parent
        self.child_nodes = []

    def add_node(self, value=None, name=None, parent=None):
        node = Tree(value, name, parent)
        if node.parent.name == 'root':
            self.child_nodes.append(node)
        else:
            parent_node = self.search_tree2(node.parent)
            if parent_node:
                parent_node.child_nodes.append(node)
                print(node.name, 'added..')
            else:
                print('Parent Node not found.')
        return node

    def print_tree(self, node):
        if node.name:
            if node.name == 'root':
                pass
            else:
                print(node.name.title() + ', ', 'age ', str(node.value) + ', ' if node.value else 'unknown' + ', ',
                      'with parent ', node.parent.name, ' and ',
                      *[node.child_nodes[i].name + ' ' for i in range(len(node.child_nodes))] if len(
                          node.child_nodes) > 0 else 'no one ', 'as children.', sep='')
            if node.child_nodes:
                for member in node.child_nodes:
                    member.print_tree(member)

    def search_tree2(self, node):
        if self.name == node.name:
            return self
        elif self.child_nodes:
            for child in self.child_nodes:
                result = child.search_tree2(node)
                if result:
                    return result
        return None

    def delete_node(self, node):
        parent = self.search_tree2(node.parent)
        for child in parent.child_nodes:
            if child.name == node.name:
                parent.child_nodes.remove(child)


family = Tree(name='root', parent=None)
rebecca = family.add_node(value=64, name='Rebecca', parent=family)
jack = family.add_node(value=64, name='Jack', parent=family)
kate = family.add_node(value=36, name='Kate', parent=jack)
randall = family.add_node(value=36, name='Randall', parent=jack)
kevin = family.add_node(value=36, name='Kevin', parent=rebecca)
becky = family.add_node(value=11, name='Becky', parent=kevin)
daisy = family.add_node(value=8, name='Daisy', parent=randall)
jen = family.add_node(value=22, name='Jen', parent=kate)
william = family.add_node(value=8, name='William', parent=daisy)
kyle = family.add_node(value=20, name='Kyle', parent=kate)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mention in your question, you want to use recursion. This means that you should call the function you are defining from the function.

When you iterate over the children of a node, it is possible to call `search_tree2` on the children. This will make sure it recurses the entire depth of the tree. It will also perform the logic you defined, on all the nodes, so you do not need to add the if conditions in the loop for the children.

Your code would then look like:

```
def search_tree2(self, node):
    if self.name == node.name:
        return self
    elif self.child_nodes:
        for child in self.child_nodes:
            result = child.seach_tree2(node)
            if result:
                return result

    # Could not find the result in any of the children
    return None
```